# How can I use JQL in the Jira UI to get 2 columns with a count of stories in a feature and count of features in an epic?

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to calculate the number of stories in a feature and the number of features in a capability (aka epic). Is there a way to use JQL in Jira to get this count as a column so I can export this information to excel?

Thanks in advance!